# How do I configure .net framework 3.5 in windows 7

Tags: .net, windows-7, config

I am trying to use the .net configuration tool in windows 7 but can not find it. Does anyone know where to download this tool from or where it is located in windows 7 (prof)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool comes with [Microsoft® Windows® Software Development Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4377f86d-c913-4b5c-b87e-ef72e5b4e065&displaylang=en)

This [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS337US337&q=mscorcfg.msc+.net+3.5&aq=0p&oq=ms&aqi=g-p3g7) might helpful too

NOTE: There's a later one for [Win7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb980924.aspx)

Comment: The ever changing answer... :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have the SDK installed, you won't have the tool. There is a command line version installed with the non-SDK version however:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CASPOL.exe

The SDK can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4377f86d-c913-4b5c-b87e-ef72e5b4e065&displaylang=en).

Comment: There is a bug in Vista SDK. Only installing .Net 2.0 Tools would not work, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/4762ce1e-c4a2-4315-8274-ee3a3e14ad13/

Answer (score 0):

.Net 3.5 is using CLR 2.0 so you can use the same security configuration tool Mscorcfg.msc from .Net 2.0 SDK.

Comment: I do not have this on my machine, but I do have .NET framework 3.5 installed