# Where is the .Net Configuration Tool (mscorcfg.msc) in Windows 7?

Tags: .net, windows-7, code-access-security

I am having trouble running a website on my new Windows 7 machine, and I think the issue is solved by [setting the runtime security policy to Full Trust](http://www.virtualsecrets.com/aspnet-visual-studio-2008-web-services-sgen.html), however I can't find that tool anywhere on my machine

I can't find it in Control Panel, the `%systemroot%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\` folders doesn't have it, and I can't even find it in the Windows 7 SDK. Can someone help me find this setting before I go insane?

Comment: Relevant thread and links to later SDK [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684782/how-do-i-configure-net-framework-3-5-in-windows-7/1684794#16847940)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to MSDN [mscorcfg was removed with the .NET framework 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bc0cxhc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

<strike>You might try to install an older .NET Framework redist to get it back.</strike>.

Installing .NET Framework 2.0 SDK should bring the file back:

> In the .NET Framework versions 1.0 and 1.1, Mscorcfg.msc is installed
>   with the NET Framework redistributable package. In the .NET Framework
>   2.0 and later versions, Mscorcfg.msc is installed with the .NET Framework 2.0 Software Development Kit (SDK).

Regarding your problem, you might want to have a look at [the security changes made in the .NET framework 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233103%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I installed the .Net Framework 2.0 SDK and the `mscorcfg.msc` file still does not exist

Comment: I'm wrong, the file does exist but it is in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\v2.0 64bit\Bin\`. I also noticed there is now a shortcut to it in the Administrative Tools. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the [.NET Framework 2.0 Software Development Kit (SDK) (x86)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=19988)

For those who cannot execute the `setup.exe` (my case on Windows 10 1909) :

Just extract it with 7zip and launch `install.exe`.
Then, the utility should be located here :

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\v2.0\Bin\mscorcfg.msc`

[image]